# Kotlin Quasar topic and channel blocking issue

Tags: kotlin, quasar

I was playing with Quasar in Kotlin and got to working with topics and channels. I was following some Java examples and wrote a little snippet. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. It just blocks the main thread and waits. I'm not quite sure what join is doing and wonder if that could be the issue?

```
public fun channelsDemo() {
    val x: Val<Int> = Val()
    val t: Topic<Int> = Topic()

    fiber {
        val c: Channel<Int> = t.subscribe(Channels.newChannel(0))
        do {
            val m = c.receive()
            System.out.println("Channel => " + (m + x.get()))
        } while (m != null)
    }.join()

    x.set(13)

    t.send(5)
    t.close()
}
```

edit:

```
public fun channelsDemo() {
    val x: Val<Int> = Val()
    val t: Topic<Int> = Topic()

    fiber {
        val c: Channel<Int> = t.subscribe(Channels.newChannel(0))
        do {
            val m = c.receive()
            System.out.println("Channel => " + (m + x.get()))
        } while (m != 40)
    }

    fiber {
        Strand.sleep(20000)

        x.set(13)

        t.send(5)
        t.send(21)
        t.send(40)
        t.close()
    }

}
```

Comment: The do {} while is not the correct flow here but I'm not sure what the best replacement is for "for (Integer m; (m = c.receive()) != null;) {}"

Comment: What is the purpose of the edit in the question?  is it fixing the question?  is it showing some solution?  History does not have to be maintained, keep the question concise and we can view the edit history if we want, or you can add a quick edit log at the bottom if you feel it invalidates some answer or comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` method tells the current *strand* (i.e. thread or fiber) to block until the strand it is called on terminated. In this case, you wait for the fiber to terminate, but it can hardly start because you haven't sent it anything yet.

To solve, assign the fiber to some local (`val f = fiber { ... }`), and only join it at the end of the program. Alternatively, don't assign it to anything and never join.

Comment: Thanks! I was noticing that it acted funny without the sleep so I threw it in another fiber and tested that way. That also led me to see an error in my do while loop.